# SocketIO creating multiple connections after reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, network-programming, client-server

I'm working on a **NodeJS** client-server project where the client is **BeagleBoneBlack**. I use `SocketIO` for sending BBB readings to server.

When I unplug the LAN cable from the server, the client and server understand that the connection is lost. When I plug it back, an issue occurs; on reconnect, the client connects again but the server connect event handler fires twice. After some time it, the server fires a disconnect but the client is still connected. For some reason, the program makes two sockets and when it understands that one of them is fake, it disconnects.

I found out that the solution to this problem is to put an event handler register outside the connection callback, and so I did this for the client side. But I don't know if it is possible to do it on server side, and I don't know how to make this work.

Client side:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://192.168.1.147:6400');
var isConnected = false;
var messageQueue = [];


socket.on('connect', function () { 
  isConnected = true;
  console.log("socket connected"); 
  socket.emit('some-event', data);
});

socket.on('connect_error', function() {
   isConnected = false;
   console.log('Failed to connect to server');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
   isConnected = false;
   console.log("socket disconnected");
});
```

Server side:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var address = socket.handshake.address;
    var idx = address.lastIndexOf(':');
    if (~idx && ~address.indexOf('.'))
        address = address.slice(idx + 1);
    console.log(address + " is connected");


    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
           console.log(address + " is disconnected");

    });

    socket.on('some-event', function (data) {
        //some code
    });

});
```

Comment: What are "BBB readings"?

Comment: BeagleBoneBlack readings...I have bluetooth dongle and I read IBeacon data on it...

Comment: hey were you able to figure out WHY this happens? aka why does registering event handlers within the connection callback cause this?